# Android Studio / com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 is underlined in red

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

When I implement google Admob this line is underlined as wrong:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Info: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0

All works fine when gradle is without Admob. When I add Admob problem appears:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1
```

I tried to change the same versions of appcompat and customtabs but its not works..

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Google Play Services (GMS) libraries are compiled with SDK 28 and depend on support library 28.0.0.

You should raise your compile SDK to 28 and all your support libraries should use version 28.0.0. These are the rules:

- Support library major version needs to match compile SDK version.
- All suppport libraries must use the same version.

After you make sure your app works in this setup consider migrating to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx). AndroidX replaces support library.